# In R plots, how can we make the length of an x-axis several times longer than the y-axis?

Tags: r, rstudio

Currently, I am trying to stretch out the x-axis of a plot to search for things like seasonality, etc. Meaning, I would possibly like my x-axis to be 6 times or so longer than my y-axis, while keeping the ticks and data the same. An example:

```
x <- rnorm(20)^2 * 1000000
plot(x)
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the x-axis above much longer than the y-axis? Thanks!

Comment: Click the corner of the window where your plot is, and drag it as much as you want.

Comment: i am currently doing this in Rstudio and it is incredibly hard to stretch and drag, is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Not easily... you could set something like `par(fin = c(3, 1))` first. What works there will depend on the size of your window, similarly adjusting the margins may be necessary. See `?par` for more details.

Comment: Or you could just save the plot out to a PNG or PDF and view the file. (Setting the height and width in the `png()` or `pdf()` call.)

Comment: Or use RStudio's "Zoom" feature, which makes resizing the window very easy.

Comment: When you ask questions about graphics output you _should_ include operating system details.

Answer (score 1):

The commands below are writing it to a .png file with different width. The files fig1.png and fig2.png are saved to your home directory.

```
png("fig1.png", width = 400, height = 300)
x <- rnorm(20)^2 * 1000000
plot(x)
dev.off()

png("fig2.png", width = 600, height = 300)
x <- rnorm(20)^2 * 1000000 #or leave this out if you want the same data x 
plot(x)
dev.off()
```